# Windows Task Scheduler job with parameter and STDOUT redirect

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a command line program that expects either no parameter or one parameter. If no parameter is supplied it prompts for the parameter with simple code like:

```
String theParameter = String.Empty;
if (args.Length == 1) theParameter = args[0];
else {
    Console.Write("Please provide theParameter: ");
    theParameter = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Some Output");
```

Interactively it works as expected:

```
> myprogram
Please provide theParameter:
{a value provided}
Some Output
```

or

```
> myprogram SomeValue
Some Output
```

or

```
> myprogram SomeValue > results.log
{Some Output in the results.log file)
```

All work as expected.

Similarly when I use the Windows 7 Task Scheduler with `myprogram SomeValue` it starts, executes and completes as expected.

However when I use `myprogram SomeValue > results.log` to redirect STDOUT to a file it starts, runs and never completes. If I manually run the job (by right clicking and running from the Task Scheduler) it throws up a console window with the `Please provide the Parameter`.

My question is: Why is the Windows Task Scheduler job short-circuiting my parameter being passed to the program if I redirect STDOUT to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output redirection [may or may not work with the Windows Task Scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/985ce84c-ac55-4fe8-b652-259d5373f747/redirect-script-output-to-file-in-task-scheduler?forum=winserverpowershell). The workaround is to run your desired command (including output redirection) inside a batch file, and to call the batch file from Task Scheduler.

```
script.bat
----------
myprogram SomeValue > results.log
```